# Embed iframe element to DOM in Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an iframe element in my JSON Object.

Here is my JSON data.

```
{
    "product_id":1
    "video":"<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/g1XPcFwyUts\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
}
```

I need embed this video(p.video) to my HTML using Angular.

Edit:

I tried

```
<div [innerHTML]="p.video">
```

But I am getting this err

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content

Comment: Well your 'video' is an iframe, just write that to the document? document.write(p.video) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html

```
<div id="videoWrapper"></div>
```

js

```
document.getElementById('videoWrapper').innerHTML = p.video
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4v3zf2b3/

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried to this. <div [innerHTML]="p.video"> But I am getting this err WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content

Comment: Thank u so much.I got slutions.